# Spring 2.5 to 4.2 upgrade issue - BeanWrapperImpl

Tags: spring, upgrade, spring-bean

I am upgrading Spring 2.5 to 4.2.
The issue is with one bean which has property type `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource`. The resource value is defined in xml as `p:location="classpath:/<the resource path>"`

This worked perfect and bean property was populated with the resource. But in 4.2 the value is not getting set.

So I debugged the code and found that the class `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl` was manipulating the value and removing `classpath:` string from actual value in Spring 2.5.

However the same is not true in 4.2 and class `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl` isn't modifying the value which results in spring not finding the resource.

Anyone faced similar situation? What solution did you apply?

Thanks,
Hanumant

**EDIT 1: code sample**

spring config file

```
    <bean class="com.test.sample.TestBean" id="testBean"
p:schemaLocation="classpath:/com/test/sample/Excalibur_combined.xsd" />
```

TestBean.java

```
public class TestBean {
private ClassPathResource             schemaLocation;

public ClassPathResource getSchemaLocation() {
    return schemaLocation;
}

public void setSchemaLocation(ClassPathResource schemaLocation) {
    this.schemaLocation = schemaLocation;
}
```

}

App.java

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/com/test/sample/spring-config.xml");
    TestBean tb = (TestBean) ap.getBean("testBean");
    try {
        URL url = tb.getSchemaLocation().getURL();
        System.out.println(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Error Message

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource
[com/test/sample/spring-config.xml] java.io.FileNotFoundException:
class path resource
[classpath:/com/test/sample/Excalibur_combined.xsd] cannot be resolved
to URL because it does not exist    at
org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)>       at com.test.sample.App.main(App.java:20)
```

However if I remove the `classpath:` from bean definition it works.

So is `classpth:` necessary in bean definition xml file?? And why it was working fine in Spring 2.5??

Comment: Please add the actual configuration to your class instead of snippets.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I have modified the original question with code

Comment: For starters in your code it should be a `Resource` and not the specific type. If it cannot be loaded it is because it doesn't exists in that location (that is what the exception is telling you). So I guess something else has changed in your structure as well (and maybe you are not *only* upgrading spring but other frameworks/tools as well).

Comment: I have created a independent maven project to test this scenario. So just by changing the spring version in pom I am able to reproduce this issue. The sample application works with 2.5 but fails with 4.2

Comment: can you add it to github?

Comment: sorry, company policy, cannot add anything to online source repos. Just to keep the comments limited. Changing the ClassPathResource to Resource works. Wondering what's happened here.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to add a independent maven project that has nothing company related in it. Anyway why it works is that you should have been programming to interfaces all along :). It works now because now the `ResourceLoader` is used to load the actual resource, the `classpath:` is now the trigger to determine where to load from. If you use a specific type that mechanism doesn't kick in and the string is directly passed to the rescource. It worked in older versions because of the hack you detected earlier.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Please add it as an answer so that I can close this question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't programming to interfaces. Instead of the concrete `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource` use `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`. When doing to the `org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor` will kick in and convert the `String` into a `Resource` instance. The location you are providing `classpath:/<the resource path>` will be passed to the `ResourceLoader` which will get the resource or throw an error if it doesn't exist.

If, however, you are using the concrete type `ClassPathResouce` directly this mechanism doesn't kick in and the location is set to what you provide `classpath:/<the resource path>`. However this is actually not a valid location for the `URL` class and that will eventually fail with the message you see.

It worked in earlier versions due to a hack/workaround/patch in the `BeanWrapperImpl` to strip the prefix.

Basically it now fails because you where doing things you shouldn't have been doing in the first place.